# using map or apply to get multiple indexes of columns using a list of column names

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas if I have column names that correspond to some data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,4)), columns=['x1', 'a', 'c', 'b'])
colnames = ['a', 'b']
```

then I can get the column positions like this :

```
[data.columns.get_loc(col) for col in colnames]
```

Is there a way to use for example a map or apply function to get this done ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? do you want the columns' positions in the list of columns? Why can't you use the list comprehension you gave in your question?

Comment: bah, sorry there was a typo in the question. but yes the indexes or positions of the columns in the dataframe, currently using a list comprehension to do it, but since colnames is an iterable there should be a way to use map or apply ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use the list comprehension—I prefer it for readability—but yes it can be written as a map:

```
map(lambda col: data.columns.get_loc(col), colnames)
```

Comment: if using python3 you'd want to wrap it in with `list()`: `list(map(lambda col: data.columns.get_loc(col), colnames))`

Answer (score 0):

That works just fine, but this is what [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) is for:

```
def get_all_locs(index, x):
    v = index.values
    a = v.argsort()
    i = a.argsort()
    return a[v[a].searchsorted(x)]

get_all_locs(data.columns, colnames)

array([1, 3])
```